# gcloud ssh -- No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to follow a simple process of ssh'ing to the instance that is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloudplatform).
Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
 Server refused our key FATAL
ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
(server sent: publickey)
```

It looks like I do everything correctly.

1. I create an new ubuntu instanse
2. Try to log in using `$ gcloud compute username@ssh example-instance --zone us-central1-a`
3. Getting a warning that ssh key is going to be generated

   ```
   WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for Google Compute Engine.
   WARNING: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\winkeygen.exe] will be executed to generate a key.
   Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/sharp-kayak-120708].
   ```
4. I get the error mentioned above

   ```
   Server refused our key
   FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
   ```

I see the keys created on both, local machine and instance (gcloud adds them to Metadata -> SSH keys). SSH is allowed in network settings.

I have tried an alternative route described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653038/unable-to-ssh-to-google-cloud):

1. generate ssh using gcloud
2. add it to pageant
3. SSH using PuTTY
4. same error:

   ```
   No supported authentication methods available
       (server sent: publickey)
   ```

Would really appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `gcloud info`? Can you also try the ssh command with `--dry-run` flag and post the output?

Comment: @Valentin 
here[link](https://gist.github.com/Vicnov/28cecbbd2bc141d40e5d) is the ouput of gcloud info

here is the --dry-run output


`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute ssh --dry-run temp-machine
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe -i C:\Users\victo\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk victo@104.197.216.86`

If I do `whoami` on the instance I get a different login name. The login name gcloud uses is the one from Windows machine.  Though what suprises me is that adding keys manually does not help either

Comment: @Valentin Looks like this issue is platform specific -- I have just repeated all the steps on a Mac machine and was able to ssh into the instance without any problems.

Comment: Are you trying to SSH into a Windows VM? Windows does not have SSH. `gcloud compute ssh` only works with Linux VMs.

Comment: I am trying to ssh FROM windows TO ubuntu and that does not work.
If I ssh FROM mac TO the same ubuntu instance I have no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I would try to remove the file C:\Users\victo\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk (or move it to a temporary place in case you need it back),  update gcloud via `gcloud components update`, then run the ssh command again. That should regenerate the key.

Comment: Updated to `Google Cloud SDK [96.0.0]`, deleted the keys, repeated the steps. Still getting the same error

Comment: Seems like a real issue. Can you please file one here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list
Did it work before? Does creating a new VM with the same OS and SSHing to it work? These are questions whose answer will probably help the team find out what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like someone has opened a file already https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=546

Comment: In case anyone else is reading this: we think the problem is limited to Windows 10 only. Can you confirm you are using windows 10 when you get this error?

Comment: Just tested it under w7 -- getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the reports.

The problem is fixed in Cloud SDK Release 98.0.0. It includes remediation that recognizes corrupt Windows key files and regenerates them on the fly.

The problem was in **google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\winkeygen.exe**. It botched the public key modulus representation in the generated **.ppk** and **.pub** files. The ssh server then interpreted the modulus as a signed bignum and bailed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to George for assistance **with work around**: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/gce-discussion/uAPNpkBJXi4

Step by step guide here:

1. Download PuTTY and PuTTYgen.
2. Generate a key with PuTTYgen. Replace the text in the comment box with your windows username. Copy and paste the code from the window into SSH keys for the project AND for the instance (go to instance, edit, scroll down to SSH key list and click "add") (not sure if both are necessary). Don't use a pass phrase.
3. Also, save as private key file. For convenience save it in your C:\Users\.ssh folder. PuTTY will need this format of key to work.
4. Open PuTTY. Add the key to the session: Connection>SSH>Auth>Browse.. point at the newly generated key file you just made in .ssh.
5. Set up the session.  Enter IP address.  Worth saving at this point - it will remember the IP and key.
6. Open...
7. Log in as:... enter your Windows username that you added as the comment in the key gen.

I'm now up and running!  Looking forward to a fix that lets the "google compute ssh  command work! Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=546

Comment: I tried this solution but still facing same issue. Any idea?